# Selecting rows in array based on value

Tags: python, arrays

I have a two-dimensional array whose elements were read from a text file. For an arbitrary number of elements, a pound sign (`#`) occurs at `twod_array[n][0]`. For each array in the second dimension that does not start with a pound sign, I want to perform a calculation. Can anyone help me? I tried using `numpy.split`, but I think that my syntax is wrong. Here is the rough format of the array:

```
twod_array = [
    ['#', author], ['#', <more strings>], [23, 345000, 234, 345],
    [<more numbers>], [<more numbers>]
    ['#', <more strings>], [<more numbers>], [<more numbers>]
]
```

Comment: Can put code snippet?

Comment: You ask, "can anyone help me?" But you don't describe what you need help with... what calculation are you trying to perform? What code have you written? Please refer to [How Do I Ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some guidelines on how to improve your first post.

Answer (score 0):

This is **really** bad explained. I understood that you want to slice a list (we call them lists on python, not arrays) using a delimiter to determine where to start and end that slice. The start delimiter is the first item on that list if it starts with a `#`, and the end delimiter is the next item that starts with the same symbol/tag/hashtag/whatever.

**1:** First you need to fix your list, make sure the strings are strings and there are commas betwen the items:

```
array = [
    ["author"],
    ["# something put here"],
    [23, 345000, 234, 345],
    ["more numers"],
    ["more numers"],
    ["# something put here"],
    ["more numers"],
    ["more numers"]
    ]
```

**2:** Then you want to find the index of those lines that you will use as delimiter.
*Note: For simplicity, the next code assumes that you will always have only 2 lines starting with `#`.*

```
start = end = None # Create empty variables
for index, item in enumerate(array): # Loop that iterates index and data
    if str(item[0]).startswith("#"): # If data on first item starts with #
        if start is None: # If start variable is unused yet
            start = index + 1 # This is the start index
        else: # If start variable is already used
            end = index # This is the end index
```

**3:** Now that we know where to start and where to end, we can just slice our list using the indexes `start` and `end` for it. We create a new list for this:

```
my_sliced_array = array[start:end]
```

**Bonus:** Feel free to use the next prints to test and see the result of the code:

```
print("printing from {} to {}".format(start, end))
print(my_sliced_array)
```